# Creating a WebRequest with cookie and return HTML C#

Tags: c#, post, web-scraping, httpwebrequest, webrequest

I'm trying to log into Amazon Seller Central account and then return the HTML from the orders page (which requires a login).  My streamreader is returning null, so something must be wrong with my code or my idea of doing this is flawed.

In the first section of this code before the `ConsoleReadline()`.  I'm POST my username and password and then I receive a cookie, which shows up in the console, but I believe, I've got the 2nd part wrong when I try to retrieve the HTML of the next URI string.

**CODE**

```
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Text;
using System.Net;


namespace HandleWebRequest
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string loginUri = "https://sellercentral.amazon.com/gp/homepage.html?";
            string orderUri =
                "https://sellercentral.amazon.com/gp/orders-v2/list/ref=ag_myo_wos3_home?byDate=shipDate&statusFilter=ItemsToShip&searchFulfillers=mfn&ignoreSearchType=1&searchType=OrderStatus&_encoding=UTF8&searchDateOption=preSelected&sortBy=OrderStatusDescending&shipSearchDateOption=noTimeLimit";
            string username = "myusernmae";
            string password = "mypassword";
            string reqString = "username=" + username + "&password=" + password;
            byte[] requestData = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(reqString);

            CookieContainer cc = new CookieContainer();
            var request = (HttpWebRequest) WebRequest.Create(loginUri);
            request.Proxy = null;
            request.CookieContainer = cc;
            request.Method = "POST";

            request.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
            request.ContentLength = requestData.Length;
            using (Stream s = request.GetRequestStream())
                s.Write(requestData, 0, requestData.Length);

            using (var response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse())
                foreach (Cookie c in response.Cookies)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(c.Name + " = " + c.Value);
                    Console.WriteLine(c.Domain);
                }

            Console.ReadLine();

            request = (HttpWebRequest) WebRequest.Create(orderUri);
            request.CookieContainer = cc;
            using (WebResponse response = request.GetResponse())
            using (Stream s = response.GetResponseStream())
            using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(s))
                File.WriteAllText("code.html", sr.ReadToEnd());

            System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("code.html");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: does it work if you print the output to console, instead of writing to file? In other words, are you even getting an output from the server at all? maybe the content length is zero?

Comment: `response` is a new object; it doesn't just inherit the request's cookie container. You need to feed the cookies from `response.Cookies` into your CookieContainer, otherwise the next request won't have them.

Comment: On a related note, `HttpWebResponse` isn't IDisposable, so there is no use putting that inside a Using statement.

Answer (score 0):

`response` is a new object; it doesn't just inherit the cookie container you put into `request`. You need to feed the cookies from `response.Cookies` into your CookieContainer, otherwise the next request won't have them:

```
foreach (Cookie c in response.Cookies)
    cc.Add(new Uri(this.m_HttpWebResponse.ResponseUri.Scheme + "://" + c.Domain), c);
request = (HttpWebRequest) WebRequest.Create(orderUri);
request.CookieContainer = cc;
```